# How can I index group elements in re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

how can I index a character in a matched group from within the re.sub match.

So I am trying to do this:

```
import re
string_test = "this.day"
string_test = re.sub("^(.*?)\.(.*?)", "\g<1>[0].\g<2>", string_test)
```

My result should be: `"t.day"`. Is it possible to somehow index the `\g<1>` group within the re.sub ? Obviously `\g<1>[0]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do indexing like above unless you use lambda function. Just change your regex like below.

```
string_test = re.sub("^(.)[^.]*\.(.*)", r"\g<1>.\g<2>", string_test)
```

or

```
>>> import re
>>> string_test = "this.day"
>>> re.sub(r"^(.)[^.]*\.(.*)", r"\1.\2", string_test)
't.day'
```

If you really want to do indexing,

```
>>> re.sub(r"^(.*?)\.(.*)", lambda m: m.group(1)[0] + '.' + m.group(2), string_test)
't.day'
>>> re.sub(r"^(.*?)(\..*)", lambda m: m.group(1)[0] + m.group(2), string_test)
't.day'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The following worked for my task "string_test = re.sub("^(.)([^.]*?)\.(.*?)", "\g<1>.\g<3>", string_test)". So there is no way to directly index the elements? I know I could group later and do something like : .group(1)[0]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a true regex ninja

Comment: One more question. Why aren't you using [^.]*?, wouldn't your regex also match "this.day.two" and do "t.two" instead of "t.day.two"?

Comment: really>? https://regex101.com/r/xQ1eF9/1 . `[^.]*` negated char class which matches any char but not of a dot zero or more times.

Comment: true, failed to notice that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that; but you can refactor the groups so they capture the parts that you do want.

```
string_test = re.sub("^(.).*?\.(.*?)", "\g<1>.\g<2>", string_test)
```

This is slightly more strict because it requires at least one character in the first group; but then so does your problem statement (so your original regex was erroneous in this regard, too).